# Convention for packages that modify commands of other packages

Tags: macros, packages

I want to write a package that modify a command of another package. Let's say for example the command is `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package so in `mynewpack.sty` file I have something like that:

```
\let\latex@includegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{<some tex code> \latex@includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
```

If in my `main.tex` file I have this

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mynewpack}
```

all goes fine, `graphicx` defines `\includegraphics` command and `mynewpack` redefines it.

But if the loading of these two packages is switched then I don't understand what happen. I expect an error because into `mynewpack.sty` I use `includegraphics` when the `graphicx` package is not yet loaded. Instead no error is produced but the inclusion of `mynewpack` has no effects (I think it is because it is loaded before `graphicx` and `graphicx` restores `includegraphics` to the default one).

**Why I don't get the error I expect in this situation?**

**How can I fix this problem?** My idea is of loading the `graphicx` package directly from the `mynewpack` one but then I don't know what happens if the also the user add the `graphicx` package inside the `main.tex`. Another possibility is using some command inside `mynewpack.sty` that delays the redefinition of `includegraphics` until all other packages are loaded but I don't know if this command exist...

Comment: I would place `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your style file, and have users not place it in their main document (though it shouldn't hurt things, in general).  It will also guarantee that it is pre-loaded, regardless of whether the user also puts it in his file or not.  If your package deals solely with modifications to an existing package (also called customization), I would sometimes name my style, using your example, `Redgraphicx.sty` or something that clues the user into its purpose.

Comment: There's no error when you say `\let\foo=\baz` and `\baz` is not defined. This justs leaves `\foo` in the same undefined status as `\baz`. You should `\RequirePackage{graphicx}` before starting to modify its macros.

Comment: To back up what Steven says, if you put `\usepackage{graphicx}` (or the equivalent but semantically better `\RequirePackage{graphicx}` then you guarantee that `graphicx` is loaded before your package and it doesn't matter if a user puts `\usepackage{graphicx}` in their preamble or not, or where they put it.

Comment: But if I use `\RequirePackage{graphicx}` inside my `.sty` file and a user put `\usepackage{graphicx}` AFTER the `\usepackage{mynewpack}` this does not overwrite the `includegraphics` command restoring it to the original definition?

Comment: The answer is no (I tried :-) ) but why not?

Comment: @Red No, the LaTeX package loading system only loads packages once. (OK, there are a few that side-step this, but that is very rare.)

Comment: @JosephWright one more question, what if the user want to load the `graphicx` package with some particular option but I have already loaded it within my package without any option?

Comment: @Red then they just need to load graphicx first and the one in your file will be ignored (by the way this must be happening in your example otherwise you would get an error on the `\renewcommand`0 and what are you doing changing my code. Disgraceful:-)

Comment: @egreg no error from the `\let` but there would be one from `\renewcommand\includegraphics` unless it is already defined. So it must be defined somewhere we haven't been shown

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you're right, that code was only a simplification, the real one has a `\newcommand\my@includegraphics` and then (based on some condition) there is a `\let\includegraphics\my@includegraphics`. Sorry for changing your code :-D

Comment: All of this is another reason we need LaTeX3, with proper separation of code from interfaces!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that in your package you have

```
\let\latex@includegraphics\includegraphics
\newcommand\variant@includegraphics[2][]{<code>\latex@includegraphics[#1]{#2}
```

and then, under some conditions, you say

```
\let\includegraphics\variant@includegraphics
```

(for instance as the “begin” part of an environment).

If `graphicx` is loaded before your package, you'll have no problem; otherwise, `\includegraphics` will not be defined at the moment the first `\let` is executed, leaving `\latex@includegraphics` undefined.

When `graphicx` is loaded after your package, a call to `\includegraphics` when not under the scope of your second `\let`. But inside that scope, you'll get an error when TeX will try to expand `\latex@includegraphics` which is undefined. If you don't, then check whether another package you load defines `\latex@includegraphics`).

So, whenever you want to modify a command's behavior (without changing its main syntax, the possibilities are adding a *-variant or an optional argument if not included in the original syntax), you need to ensure the command is defined at the moment you `\let` a new control sequence to it. Therefore you should say

```
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
```

so it will be immaterial whether the end user loads it before or after your package. There may be problems if a user loads `graphicx` with options, so you should tell in your package's documentation that `graphicx` is required, so it should be loaded in advance if options need to be passed to it.

Actually, the situation with `\includegraphics` is rather complicated. Some packages *do* modify it, in particular some TikZ related ones. Then it's best to use `\LetLtxMacro` instead of `\let`. However, this would break if somebody uses the `*` variant (rare usage, but possible), so you must tell in the documentation that the `*` variant is not supported and that the `clip` option must be specified instead.